# Run one particular controller action through the cron in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, cron, rake, whenever

I have to run one particular controller action through the cron in rails. My code for this is:

```
every 1.minutes do
    runner "Count.get_value", output: { error: "#{path}/log/error.log", standard: "#{path}/log/cron.log" }
end
```

Above code works fine with model action, but I need to run controller action through the cron. Can someone help me?

Comment: man try this `creator = Controller.action`  `creator.process`

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, controllers are for comunicating between views and models.

I suppose the problem is that you have some model logic in your controller and that is why you need to call the controller. Move your logic to where it belongs (the model) and use the cron you are using.

Comment: Thank you for your ans @Juan Manuel Rodulfo Salcedo, but in model file that logic was not working,because am handling shopify api inside the model file.kindly give some other ideas.

Comment: Any how thanks for your ans@Juan Manuel Rodulfo Salcedo, it works the ordinary rails app and ordinary logic.

Comment: use a cron with a wget or curl to the controller's action.

Comment: Hi dude thanks for your help @Juan Manuel Rodulfo Salcedo,could u pls send some reference link fot this problem.

Comment: Hi am finally found the solution for this one.Thanks for your help @Juan Manuel Rodulfo Salcedo, the actual problem is occured in the API section.Now its solved.